# Зачем нужно приведение типов в функции обратного вызова android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, callback

В примерах кода на [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ru) есть конструкция передачи данных от фрагмента к активности. Там используется интерфейс обратного вызова. Разбираю код построчно и интересует вопрос: зачем приводить активность к типу onArticleSelectedListener (`mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;`)?

Код фрагмента:

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    ...
    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnArticleSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(Uri articleUri);
    } 
    OnArticleSelectedListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Append the clicked item's row ID with the content provider Uri
        Uri noteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ArticleColumns.CONTENT_URI, id);
        // Send the event and Uri to the host activity
        mListener.onArticleSelected(noteUri);
    }
  }
```

В активности происходит переопределение метода интерфейса onArticleSelected.

Comment: для того, чтобы убедиться, что ваш activity наследует `OnArticleSelectedListener` и, соответственно, безопасно вызвать метод `mListener.onArticleSelected`, либо, если не наследует, то выбросить исключение `ClassCastException` с последствиями

Comment: Спасибо за очень быстрый ответ. Можете привести пример ситуации когда activity не унаследует OnArticleSelectedListener

Comment: что тут приводить ?! у класса активити (или родительских классов) нет имплементации некого интерфейса, в котором объявлен onArticleSelected метод

Comment: Спасибо огромное